# Pandas: pivot comma delimited column into multiple columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pivot, dummy-variable

I have the following Pandas DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'type': ['a,b,c,d', 'b,d', 'c,e', np.nan]})
```

[image]

I need to split the type column based on the commma delimiter and pivot the values into multiple columns to get this

[image]

I looked at Pandas documentation for pivot() and also searched stackoverflow. I did not find anything that seems to achieve (directly or indirectly) what I need to do here. Any suggestions?

Edited:

enke's solution works using Pandas 1.3.5. However it does not work using the latest version 1.4.1. Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `str.get_dummies` to get the dummy variables; then `join` back to `df`:

```
out = df[['id']].join(df['type'].str.get_dummies(sep=',').add_prefix('type_').replace(0, float('nan')))
```

Output:

```
   id  type_a  type_b  type_c  type_d  type_e
0   1     1.0     1.0     1.0     1.0     NaN
1   2     NaN     1.0     NaN     1.0     NaN
2   3     NaN     NaN     1.0     NaN     1.0
3   4     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

Comment: Enke's code works using Pandas 1.3.5. However it does not quite work using the latest version (1.4.1). type B and C are duplicated in the result. See the screenshot in my edited post.

Comment: @Hui no that's because you have space between the letters, use `sep=', '` instead and you should be good.